# How to send a variable of type File[] through sockets in JAVA

Tags: java, file, sockets

I have implemented a Java Client Server Application.

The server is having a list of files stored in the folder as:

```
File[] list=folder.listFiles();
```

I want to send this variable list through socket to the client.
How to do this in JAVA

Thanx in advance

Comment: For what purpose? File is basically just a file name. It doesn't have any meaning at the other end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, basically you can't. You should think of a socket as transmitting a stream of bytes.  A File object contains local-machine state, like the file pointer.  If you want to do something similar, you should store something like path names for each File's underlying file and then create File objects on the other side.

Comment: Can we convert the file list in the array to string and send them one by one through the sockets?

Comment: Or better, use `File.list()` which already returns a string containing the list of file paths.

Answer (score 0):

**Send each file in the File[] my looping over them and following the below simple steps:**

**-** Open `ServerSocket` on server side.

**-** Create `Socket` on client side. Connect to server with `bind`.

**-** Using `getOutputStream` method on Socket get the output stream.

**- Write your file to the output stream**.  // most important part 
    (Use `FileInputStream`, `BufferedInputStream`)

**-** Close the socket.